# What's the type 'Type' in golang?

Tags: go

I saw the definition of slice append function in doc:

```golang
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

Then I turned to the definition of `Type`:

```golang
// Type is here for the purposes of documentation only. It is a stand-in
// for any Go type, but represents the same type for any given function
// invocation.
type Type int
```

Why the type `Type` is defined as int? Why this type can represent any type? Is this just a trick of go compiler?

Comment: *"Is this just a trick of go compiler?"* -- No, it is there for the `go doc` and `godoc` tools, hence the *"Type is here for the purposes of documentation only."*.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you, So this is for doc only? The real code is not written in library but in the compiler?

Comment: Something like that, the `builtin` package contains only one file with no implementation whatsoever, all it contains are declarations and documentations. And no actual program ever does, nor needs to, import `"builtin"`. See: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/builtin/builtin.go